# Merge objects to make dynamic rethinkdb query

Tags: php, rethinkdb

I'm trying to dynamicly make my rethinkdb queries but whey I use the following code:

```
<?php
require_once "rdb/rdb.php";

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
$conditions = [];
$conn = r\connect('10.7.96.5:28015');

if (isset($_GET["alive"])) {
    $conditions[] = r\row("alive")->eq("true" === $_GET["alive"]);
}

if (isset($_GET["times_alive"])) {
    $conditions[] = r\row("times_alive")->ge((int) $_GET["times_alive"]);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($conditions); $i++) {
    if (0 == $i) {
        $condition = $conditions[$i];
    } else {
        $condition .= ->rAnd($conditions[$i]);
    }
}

$result = r\db('proxyscrape')->table("proxies")->filter(
    $condition
)->run($conn);

foreach ($result as $doc) {
    print_r($doc);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in /var/www/html/test3.php on line 20
```

The expected result I'm looking for in $condition is

```
r\row("alive")->eq("true" === $_GET["alive"])->rAnd(r\row("times_alive")->ge((int) $_GET["times_alive"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by changing

```
$condition .= ->rAnd($conditions[$i]);
```

To

```
$condition = $condition->rAnd($conditions[$i]);
```